# Mounting ceph fails with "mount error 5 = Input/output error"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ceph

I have tried to create a ceph filesystem in a single host, for testing purposes, with the following conf file

```
[global]
        log file = /var/log/ceph/$name.log
        pid file = /var/run/ceph/$name.pid
[mon]
        mon data = /srv/ceph/mon/$name
[mon.mio]
host = penny
mon addr = 127.0.0.1:6789
[mds]
[mds.mio]
host = penny
[osd]
osd data = /srv/ceph/osd/$name
osd journal = /srv/ceph/osd/$name/journal
osd journal size = 1000 ; journal size, in megabytes
[osd.0]
host = penny
devs = /dev/loop1
```

/dev/loop1 is formatted with XFS and is actually a file with 500Mbs (although that shouldn't matter much) Everything works pretty much OK, and health shows:

```
 sudo ceph -s
2013-12-12 21:14:44.387240    pg v111: 198 pgs: 198 active+clean; 8730 bytes data, 79237 MB used, 20133 MB / 102 GB avail
2013-12-12 21:14:44.388542   mds e6: 1/1/1 up {0=mio=up:active}
2013-12-12 21:14:44.388605   osd e3: 1 osds: 1 up, 1 in
2013-12-12 21:14:44.388738   log 2013-12-12 21:14:32.739326 osd.0 127.0.0.1:6801/8834 181 : [INF] 2.30 scrub ok
2013-12-12 21:14:44.388922   mon e1: 1 mons at {mio=127.0.0.1:6789/0}
```

but when I try to mount the filesystem

```
sudo mount -t ceph penny:/ /mnt/ceph
mount error 5 = Input/output error
```

Usual answers point to ceph-mds not running, but it's actually working:

```
root      8771  0.0  0.0 574092  4376 ?        Ssl  20:43   0:00 /usr/bin/ceph-mds -i mio -c /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
```

In fact, I managed to make it work previously using these instructions http://blog.bob.sh/2012/02/basic-ceph-storage-kvm-virtualisation.html verbatim previously, but after I tried again I obtained the same problem. Any idea of what might have failed?

**Update** as indicated by the comment, dmesg shows a problem

```
[ 6715.712211] libceph: mon0 [::1]:6789 connection failed
[ 6725.728230] libceph: mon1 127.0.1.1:6789 connection failed
```

Comment: Is there any information displayed in dmesg

Comment: It shows effectively an error. I have edited the question to show it. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use the IP address instead of the hostname. The kernel should be able to resolve it correctly, but it's a good thing to rule out.

Comment: Specifically, 127.0.0.1, rather than 1.1 or the IPv6 lookup that seems to have resolved.

Comment: It works with sudo mount -t ceph 127.0.0.1:/ /mnt/ceph There was an error in /etc/hosts that resolver penny to 127.0.1.1. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. It's probably something to do with the /etc/hosts, but I'm not very knowledable about the exact configuration required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure communication is in place between ceph mds node and client node, (Port 6800 & 6801)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 127.0.0.1. It looks like the kernel is resolving the hostname, but 127.0.1.1 is weird, and maybe it isn't responding to IPv6 loopback.